# TODO items not showing up in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express, todo

The TODO list items aren't showing up in Visual Studio Express 2012 for C++.

**Why are the TODO list items not showing up?**

This question has been asked before, but none of the answers have resolved my issue. I have done the following:

---

### What I have already tried:

- Checking formatting was:
  `//TODO test`
- Checking the task list **drop down** was set to **Comments**
- Made sure the **file** with the comment was **open and selected**
- Set **Enumerate Comment Tasks** to **True** under:
  *Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Miscellaneous->Enumerate Comment Tasks*
- **Restarting** the application

---

### **Solution:**

- JBentley's first suggestion fixed the issue. I was **missing** the **colon**, so the correct format was:
  `//TODO: text`

Comment: I find it very odd that this was closed as off-topic. What is off-topic about it? It's a specific question relating to an issue involving *software tools commonly used by programmers* (from the FAQ). It addresses a real problem that other programmers will no doubt face when trying to use the same feature.

Comment: I don't know either. I'm not sure how to go about fixing it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a colon:

```
//TODO: text
//   ^^^
//  colon
```

This worked for me (with `Enumerate Comment Tasks` set to `True`, as you mentioned) in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Caveat: the file needs to be open AND active for it to appear in the task list in C++, according to the [Visual Studio 2008 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> With Visual Basic and Visual C#, the Task List displays all the
>   comments in the solution. With Visual C++ projects, the Task List
>   displays only the comments that are found in the file that is
>   currently active in the editor.

I couldn't find the equivalent documentation for any later versions, but the behaviour seems to be unmodified in Visual Studio 2012 which is a shame because it makes the feature rather limited in usefulness.